# Running Python script Permission Denied in mac terminal

Tags: python, sudo

Tried some solutions I found online such as running:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.atom
```

However it returns a strange answer requesting a password. Screenshot below.

Any advice? [image]

Comment: `sudo` is not the answer you’re looking for, and `chown ~/.atom` will not make a script in the current directory executable.  I’d hope a basic Web search for “Python permission denied” would give you some direction here.

Comment: Nothing.. solution online lead me to the sudo answer.

Answer (score 1):

sudo means you're changing to super user. If you have an Administrator account, your sudo password is your normal password. If you do not, you'll need to ask your admin

Comment: I put my system password - permission still denied to run the program. Any ideas?

Comment: did sudo successfully accept your password, if you did. What steps are you doing to run your python script?

Comment: Sudo accepted my password. Then I simply drag and drop my python code file into terminal. It worked earlier today, not sure what changed.

Comment: things do check, do you have a #!/usr/bin/env python, on the top of your python code? And if you can get to your python script via command-line, chmod u+x on the python file. All else fails, navigate to the file and run python script.py

Answer (score 0):

Well, calling `sudo <command> ...` actually calls [sudo](https://superuser.com/questions/185441/what-does-the-sudo-command-do) for running the `<command>` with `root` privilidges. Usually `sudo` asks you for your user password and can be exacuted only if your user is allowed to run sudo i.e. it is [added to sudoers file](https://stuntcoders.com/add-user-to-sudoers-on-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: drag and drop the project into the terminal (it will automatically get the project path)

Step 2: Remove the last file name ends with .py

step 3: Give ls -l command

step 4: you can get the file name what you removed above

Step 5: Python3 filename.py(EX:if the file name is main then Python3 main.py)